# How to add text to each individual-exported PDF report in R or RMarkdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown

Thanks for reading this question. I have a dataset containing five participants/rows with 8 variables/columns. I was able to export each participant/row of the dataset in a separate pdf file, and name that exported pdf file according to the participant name (Thanks to @Jilber Urbina). I need help with explaining how to add text (nicely formatted) before the table, the text should say something like :"Dear Client, This report provides a summary of your scores on the performance test" Attached is an explanatory code to explain this question.

```
# Creating a dataset for explanation:
df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 8, nrow = 5))
x <- c("Participants", "V1","V2", "V3",  "V4","V5", "V6","V7")
colnames(df) <- x

df$Participants= c("Elizabeth",
                   "Emily",
                   "Cristie",
                   "Orville",
                   "Janetta")
df$V1 = runif(5, min=0, max=10)
df$V2 = runif(5, min=0, max=10)
df$V3 = runif(5, min=0, max=10)
df$V4 = runif(5, min=0, max=10)
df$V5 = runif(5, min=0, max=10)
df$V6 = runif(5, min=0, max=10)
df$V7 = runif(5, min=0, max=10)

summary(df)

# Printing each participant/row in individual report:

library(gridExtra)
apply(df, 1, function(x){
  pdf(paste0(x[1], ".pdf"), width=10)
  grid.table(data.frame(t(x)))
  dev.off()
})
```

How to add a text/message to each individual report so the clients can read the text/message and also look at their performance scores? Thank you much.

Comment: Have you thought about rendering an A4 pdf report using `rmarkdown::render`? You would have to create a simple RMarkdown template and can then input individual data using the YAML option `params`.

Comment: Thanks, Martin. I don't know how I could add it within the "apply" function provided in the main question above. Could you please provide an example? Thanks again. @MartinSchmelzer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using the pdf device you can render rmarkdown documents. Take this R script

```
# Creating a dataset for explanation:
df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 8, nrow = 5))
x <- c("Participants", "V1","V2", "V3",  "V4","V5", "V6","V7")
colnames(df) <- x

df$Participants <- c("Elizabeth", "Emily", "Cristie", "Orville","Janetta")
df$V1 = runif(5, min=0, max=10)
df$V2 = runif(5, min=0, max=10)
df$V3 = runif(5, min=0, max=10)
df$V4 = runif(5, min=0, max=10)
df$V5 = runif(5, min=0, max=10)
df$V6 = runif(5, min=0, max=10)
df$V7 = runif(5, min=0, max=10)

summary(df)

# Printing each participant/row in individual report:
apply(df, 1, function(x){
  print(x)
  fname <- paste0(x[1], ".pdf")
  rmarkdown::render(input="template.Rmd", 
                    output_file = fname,
                    output_format = "pdf_document",
                    params = list(id=x[1], data=x[-1]))
})
```

which renders the rmarkdown document *template.Rmd* using different parameters. Its content is

````
---
output: pdf_document
params:
  id: NULL
  data: NULL
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## Evaluation

Dear `r params$id`, This report provides a summary of your scores on the performance test.

```{r, echo=F}
knitr::kable(params$data)
```
````

You can style the output however you like. This simple template gives you

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thanks much, @martinschmelzer. I appreciate your assistance

Comment: I wonder if you could help me out with a slightly (i think) more complicated example of a similar case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69904796/create-individual-row-wise-per-participant-pdf-report-in-r-markdown-from-a-s