# Create individual (row-wise / per participant) pdf report in R markdown from a single database

Tags: r, r-markdown, qualtrics, export-to-pdf

I'm working with a long (280 questions) survey hosted by Qualtrics.

As part of my workflow, I download data directly from qualtrics using the `qualtRics` package for `R`:

```
df<-fetch_survey("SV_xxxxxxxx", time_zone = "Europe/Berlin", force_request = T,
                 start_date = "2021-11-01", convert = F, label = T, include_display_order = F)
```

As a result I get a `tbl_df` that looks similar to this:

```
df<-structure(list(StartDate = structure(c(1636487307, 1636487369
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "Europe/Berlin", label = c(StartDate = "Start Date")), 
    EndDate = structure(c(1636487364, 1636487424), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = "Europe/Berlin", label = c(EndDate = "End Date")), 
    Status = structure(c("IP Address", "IP Address"), label = c(Status = "Response Type")), 
    IPAddress = structure(c("213.134.172.108", "213.134.172.108"
    ), label = c(IPAddress = "IP Address")), Progress = structure(c(100, 
    100), label = c(Progress = "Progress")), `Duration (in seconds)` = structure(c(57, 
    55), label = c(`Duration (in seconds)` = "Duration (in seconds)")), 
    Finished = structure(c(TRUE, TRUE), label = c(Finished = "Finished")), 
    RecordedDate = structure(c(1636487364, 1636487424), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = "Europe/Berlin", label = c(RecordedDate = "Recorded Date")), 
    ResponseId = structure(c("R_29nRhq8tofKc2Us", "R_2uOJfVuxexKnO0J"
    ), label = c(ResponseId = "Response ID")), RecipientLastName = structure(c(NA, 
    NA), label = c(RecipientLastName = "Recipient Last Name")), 
    RecipientFirstName = structure(c(NA, NA), label = c(RecipientFirstName = "Recipient First Name")), 
    RecipientEmail = structure(c(NA, NA), label = c(RecipientEmail = "Recipient Email")), 
    ExternalReference = structure(c(NA, NA), label = c(ExternalReference = "External Data Reference")), 
    LocationLatitude = structure(c(52.2483978271484, 52.2483978271484
    ), label = c(LocationLatitude = "Location Latitude")), LocationLongitude = structure(c(21.0025939941406, 
    21.0025939941406), label = c(LocationLongitude = "Location Longitude")), 
    DistributionChannel = structure(c("anonymous", "anonymous"
    ), label = c(DistributionChannel = "Distribution Channel")), 
    UserLanguage = structure(c("EN", "EN"), label = c(UserLanguage = "User Language")), 
    name1 = structure(c("John", "Mary"), label = c(name1 = "First name")), 
    name2 = structure(c("Doe", "Jane"), label = c(name2 = "Birth Name")), 
    yob = structure(c(1982, 1964), label = c(yob = "Year of birth")), 
    mail = structure(c("mail@gmail.com", "mj@green.com"), label = c(mail = "e-mail:")), 
    Q5_1 = structure(c("Strongly disagree", "Strongly agree"), label = c(Q5_1 = "Some scales - question1")), 
    Q5_2 = structure(c("Somewhat disagree", "Strongly agree"), label = c(Q5_2 = "Some scales - question2")), 
    Q5_3 = structure(c("Neither agree nor disagree", "Somewhat agree"
    ), label = c(Q5_3 = "Some scales - question3")), q1 = structure(c("Yes", 
    "No"), label = c(q1 = "Example of a conditional item, where the YES answer leads to an other question;")), 
    q2 = structure(c("No", NA), label = c(q2 = "So... you clicked yes, right?")), 
    `pets#1_1_1` = structure(c("Dizzie", "no pet"), label = c(`pets#1_1_1` = "Click to write the question text - Pet - Pet 1 - name")), 
    `pets#1_2_1` = structure(c("Jumbo", NA), label = c(`pets#1_2_1` = "Click to write the question text - Pet - Pet 2 - name")), 
    `pets#1_3_1` = structure(c(NA, "no pet"), label = c(`pets#1_3_1` = "Click to write the question text - Pet - Pet 3 - name")), 
    `pets#2_1_1` = structure(c(3, 0), label = c(`pets#2_1_1` = "Click to write the question text - Pet - Pet 1 - age")), 
    `pets#2_2_1` = structure(c(NA, NA), label = c(`pets#2_2_1` = "Click to write the question text - Pet - Pet 2 - age")), 
    `pets#2_3_1` = structure(c(NA, "x"), label = c(`pets#2_3_1` = "Click to write the question text - Pet - Pet 3 - age")), 
    Q9 = structure(c("was super awesome, but im having problems with this report :/", 
    "i dont know what im doing here"), label = c(Q9 = "Decribe how you felt today:"))), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), column_map = structure(list(qname = c("StartDate", 
"EndDate", "Status", "IPAddress", "Progress", "Duration (in seconds)", 
"Finished", "RecordedDate", "ResponseId", "RecipientLastName", 
"RecipientFirstName", "RecipientEmail", "ExternalReference", 
"LocationLatitude", "LocationLongitude", "DistributionChannel", 
"UserLanguage", "name1", "name2", "yob", "mail", "Q5_1", "Q5_2", 
"Q5_3", "q1", "q2", "pets#1_1_1", "pets#1_2_1", "pets#1_3_1", 
"pets#2_1_1", "pets#2_2_1", "pets#2_3_1", "Q9"), description = c("Start Date", 
"End Date", "Response Type", "IP Address", "Progress", "Duration (in seconds)", 
"Finished", "Recorded Date", "Response ID", "Recipient Last Name", 
"Recipient First Name", "Recipient Email", "External Data Reference", 
"Location Latitude", "Location Longitude", "Distribution Channel", 
"User Language", "First name", "Birth Name", "Year of birth", 
"e-mail:", "Some scales - question1", "Some scales - question2", 
"Some scales - question3", "Example of a conditional item, where the YES answer leads to an other question;", 
"So... you clicked yes, right?", "Click to write the question text - Pet - Pet 1 - name", 
"Click to write the question text - Pet - Pet 2 - name", "Click to write the question text - Pet - Pet 3 - name", 
"Click to write the question text - Pet - Pet 1 - age", "Click to write the question text - Pet - Pet 2 - age", 
"Click to write the question text - Pet - Pet 3 - age", "Decribe how you felt today:"
), main = c("Start Date", "End Date", "Response Type", "IP Address", 
"Progress", "Duration (in seconds)", "Finished", "Recorded Date", 
"Response ID", "Recipient Last Name", "Recipient First Name", 
"Recipient Email", "External Data Reference", "Location Latitude", 
"Location Longitude", "Distribution Channel", "User Language", 
"First name", "Birth Name", "Year of birth", "e-mail:", "Some scales", 
"Some scales", "Some scales", "Example of a conditional item, where the YES answer leads to an other question;", 
"So... you clicked yes, right?", "Click to write the question text", 
"Click to write the question text", "Click to write the question text", 
"Click to write the question text", "Click to write the question text", 
"Click to write the question text", "Decribe how you felt today:"
), sub = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "question1", "question2", "question3", 
"", "", "Pet - Pet 1 - name", "Pet - Pet 2 - name", "Pet - Pet 3 - name", 
"Pet - Pet 1 - age", "Pet - Pet 2 - age", "Pet - Pet 3 - age", 
""), ImportId = c("startDate", "endDate", "status", "ipAddress", 
"progress", "duration", "finished", "recordedDate", "_recordId", 
"recipientLastName", "recipientFirstName", "recipientEmail", 
"externalDataReference", "locationLatitude", "locationLongitude", 
"distributionChannel", "userLanguage", "QID1_TEXT", "QID2_TEXT", 
"QID3_TEXT", "QID4_TEXT", "QID5_1", "QID5_2", "QID5_3", "QID6", 
"QID7", "QID8#1_1_1", "QID8#1_2_1", "QID8#1_3_1", "QID8#2_1_1", 
"QID8#2_2_1", "QID8#2_3_1", "QID9_TEXT"), timeZone = c("Europe/Berlin", 
"Europe/Berlin", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Europe/Berlin", NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), choiceId = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-33L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")))
```

What I would like to do, is to create a PDF report with all question labels and corresponding responses per single user (rowwise) - nicely formatted for reading.

I came across this question: [How to add text to each individual-exported PDF report in R or RMarkdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55934538/how-to-add-text-to-each-individual-exported-pdf-report-in-r-or-rmarkdown) but wanted to further modify resulting filename and eventually got something wrong.

**Filenames are as I want, but**

**1. the printed table is oriented horizontally and not vertically.
2. column names are printed and not column labels.**

Here is my code for generating the pdfs

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  data <- slice(df, i)
  rmarkdown::render('test.Rmd',
                    output_file = paste(data$name2, "_", data$name2, "_", data$yob, "_", data$StartDate, 
                                        '.pdf', sep=''))
  i <- i + 1
}
```

and the `test.Rmd`

````
---
header-includes:
- \usepackage{booktabs}
- \usepackage{longtable}
- \usepackage{array}
- \usepackage{multirow}
- \usepackage{wrapfig}
- \usepackage{float}
- \usepackage{colortbl}
- \usepackage{pdflscape}
- \usepackage{tabu}
- \usepackage{threeparttable}
- \usepackage{threeparttablex}
- \usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
- \usepackage{makecell}
- \usepackage{xcolor}
title:  "Pacjent: `r data$name1` `r data$name2`" 
author: "YOB: `r data$yob`; e-mail: `r data$mail`" 
date: "date: `r data$StartDate`"
output:
  pdf_document:
  toc: false
editor_options: 
  chunk_output_type: console
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo =FALSE)
```

```{r}
library(kableExtra)
library(strengejacke)
library(tidyverse)
```

```{r}
kbl(data, longtable = T, booktabs = T) %>% kable_styling(latex_options = c("repeat_header", "striped"), full_width = F) %>%
  column_spec(1, width = "10em") %>%
  column_spec(2, width = "30em")
```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rmarkdown documents have parameters (`params` in the yaml header).
Here, it is a list which is one row of the df thus one person.
This list is in vertically aligned long format after enframing ready to be printed by kable.
Names can be set by attribute lables using `names(x) <- x %>% attr("label")`.

File `test.Rmd`:

````
---
title:  "Pacjent: `r data$name1` `r data$name2`" 
author: "YOB: `r data$yob`; e-mail: `r data$mail`" 
date: "date: `r data$StartDate`"
params:
  data: NULL
output: pdf_document
---


```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
````

```
library(kableExtra)
library(tidyverse)
```

```
names(data) <- data %>% map(~ .x %>% attr("label"))
data %>%
  # list to long format table (vartically aligned)
  enframe() %>%
  mutate(value = value %>% as.character()) %>%
  kable() %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = "scale_down")
```

R - code:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  data <- slice(df, i) %>% as.list()
  rmarkdown::render("test.Rmd",
    params = list(data = data),
    output_file = paste(data$name2, "_", data$name2, "_", data$yob, "_", data$StartDate,
      ".pdf",
      sep = ""
    )
  )
}
```

Example result:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Wasnt aware of the `enframe()` function - thanks!